# How to fix the Error "Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID" in Azure DevOps release pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines

I have created the app service in existing internal app service environment. And then I’m trying to deploy the source code into above app service using Azure DevOps CI & CD pipelines. But, in the release pipeline I’m getting the below error message in Azure DevOps:

> Error: Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID
> More Information:  Could not connect to the remote computer ("xx-xxxx-v1-api-dev.scm.xxx-int-nonp.xxxcloudapps.com"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.
> Error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xx-xxxx-v1-api-dev.scm.xxx-int-nonp.xxxxcloudapps.com'
> Error count: 1.

Note: I’m using self-hosted agent in the release pipeline. I have tried to access Kudu environment for the above service in the private virtual machine. But, the kudu not opening.

So, please suggest me how to fix the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set/add the following to the Application setting and see if it helps.

Name:  WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM

Value: false

If I have understood your issue correctly (using private link).
For accessing the Kudu console, or Kudu REST API (deployment with Azure DevOps self-hosted agents for example), you must create `two records` in your Azure DNS private zone or your custom DNS server. Kindly check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#dns) for more details. If you haven't added the records, kindly see if that works.

**Name                                                            Type          Value**

mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net         **A**    PrivateEndpointIP

mywebapp.scm.privatelink.azurewebsites.net  **A**   PrivateEndpointIP

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#dns

Ensure that the release pipeline is running in the right host. Because the endpoint is private for the SCM too, the DevOps Agent must be in a network with access with the endpoint, so mandatory to use self-hosted Devops Agent.

Kindly see this doc for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#dns

If the issue still persists, kindly capture a network trace/HAR or client-side HTTP log/review the logs.
P.S. Kindly do not share any PII data on the public forum for your privacy.

Comment: Ensure that the Azure DevOps build agent is on the same VNET (subnet can be different) as the Internal Load Balancer (ILB) of ASE. This will enable the agent to pull code from Azure DevOps and deploy to ASE.

If you are using Azure DevOps, the agent need not be accessible from internet but needs only outbound access to connect to Azure DevOps Service.

See this -https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

Comment: @AjayKuamr, Yes, Azure DevOps build agent is on the same VNET as the internal ILB of ASE.